# Exception (integer overflow) when initializing 64-bit Mersenne Twister

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, random, numbers, 64-bit

I am using the 64-bit verison of the Mersenne Twister, specifically the version:

```
 A C-program for MT19937-64 (2004/9/29 version).
 Coded by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto.
```

and am receiving an integer overflow when compiling into the Release but don't get the exception during run-time in Debug.  **I have integer overflow turned OFF in the Advanced Compile options.**

The exception is being thrown on the mt(mti) = .... line inside the loop.

Strangely, I am getting this exception now every run-time in Debug compile, so did something creep into the Intel i7 floating point registers, such that I need to power down and then power up to wipe memory?

Lastly, why does initialization in Release throw the exception all the time, but not initializing in Debug?

```
' The array for the state vector 
Friend Shared mt(DefineConstants.NN - 1) As ULong
' mti==NN+1 means mt[NN] is not initialized 
Friend Shared mti As Integer = DefineConstants.NN+1

' initializes mt[NN] with a seed 
Public Shared Sub init_genrand64(ByVal seed As ULong)
    mt(0) = seed
    For mti = 1 To DefineConstants.NN - 1
        mt(mti) = (6364136223846793005UL * (mt(mti - 1) Xor (mt(mti - 1) >> 62)) + mti)
    Next mti
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signed Integer data types only go to 32 bits

Unsigned Integer data types only got to 32 bits

For 64 bits of data you should use LONG or ULONG

The reason the integer OVERFLOWS is because the data type is not large enough to hold your 64 bits of data!

change your mti to LONG type

and if you need to use fractions and decimal points instead of WHOLE numbers

then change your mti to DECIMAL type